# Does using string indexes for arrays slow things down (or: why am I sometimes missing values at random)

Tags: php

I've hastily implemented a botched together translation system for our aplication and currently i'm storing the different words and expressions as $_SESSION['translate']['string_key']. I don't know how wrong doing it this way is, but right now I gotta do what boss tells me so it will probably stay this way.

Also, the 'string_key' can get pretty lengthy as it's usually the word/expression to be translated in the default language + an optional flag (for things that sound the same in the default language but have different translations in some other language) for example (add-form_submit vs add-imperative).

Now on to the problem. I'm having trouble with missing text in some instances (not much of it, usually one item per session). It seems to be random yet some of the words go missing more often than others and I'm wondering if it has anything to do with the long string indexes used for some of them or maybe there's too much stuff in the session.

I'm not looking for a solution to my problem just wanna know if the size of the index and/or the size of the session could have the described impact on our aplication.

Comment: The limit on the array key is controlled by script's memory limit. Things missing randomly don't occur just like that and if you have reached that limit, PHP would raise a fatal error so it's not an issue with the key length, unless you're using Suhosin patch which limits key lengt to 64 chars or similar (by default).

Answer (score 1):

Session data is stored in files, and is meant for small, important pieces of information, such as IDs for data stored on local disks. You should refrain from misusing the $_SESSION global var like this.

Comment: Well i'm aware of that but since i'm a 1 man development team involved in a small ever expanding project for a small company, everything needs to be done fast above all else. And doing it like this seems to be the fastest way.

Comment: Yeah, I know how that feels (especially now), but the least you could do is just code 1 php file to store data locally and whenever you want to get or set $_SESSION['translate']['...'] you can call the functions in that file instead. I'm just trying to give some advice

Comment: @Bogdan: That kind of "fast" will eventually bring you to a standstill. Get acquainted with the concept of technical debt and explain it to your boss: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt

Comment: `$_SESSION` is not meant for small pieces of info, it's meant to persist data across URLs, and it's arbitrary whether someone will store 1kb or 1gb of data in their session.

Comment: Session data ($_SESSION) is loaded onto memory when a script is run. I don't think the server will survive loading 1gb of data into its RAM